# How do edit controls that were created in C# during runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml

So i have this block of code and i have a button called AddNewButton which adds a StackPanel into a already created StackPanel called MainStackPanel which is irrelevant but the "GroupPanel" has child controls such as "GroupName", "GroupTextBox" and "GroupEdit".

Now the "GroupEdit" button has a click event that runs the void named "GroupEdit_Click" and in that void i use `Button GroupEdit1 = sender as Button;` Now this works and makes me able to access the buttons properties and change content but my problem is: How do i access the other controls such as "GroupPanel", "GroupName" and "GroupTextBox". I will use the AddNewButton a few times so when i access the separate controls they need to be accessed seperately

I tried to get rid of as much unnecessary code.

```
private void AddNewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     StackPanel GroupPanel = new StackPanel();

     TextBlock GroupName = new TextBlock();
     GroupName.Text = "Group ";

     TextBox GroupTextBox = new TextBox();
     GroupTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

     Button GroupEdit = new Button();
     GroupEdit.Content = "Edit Group";
     GroupEdit.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(GroupEdit_Click);

     GroupPanel.Children.Add(GroupName);
     GroupPanel.Children.Add(GroupTextBox);
     GroupPanel.Children.Add(GroupEdit);
}

private void GroupEdit_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Button GroupEdit1 = sender as Button;
     GroupEdit1.Content = "Done";
     //Now how do i access these controls?
     GroupName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     GroupTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     }
}
```

Comment: The scoping of the new controls is local to the button click, so you will have to iterate through the form's controls with the GroupEdit_Click event handler. Kind of a discovery process of sorts.

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML and databinding, whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maintain a private List of your dynamically added GroupEdit controls and assign them numbered tags.

```
private List<TextBox> dynamicGroupEdits = new List<TextBox>();

private void AddNewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    dynamicGroupEdits.Add(GroupEdit);

    GroupEdit.Tag = dynamicGroupEdits.Count;
    GroupPanel.Tag = GroupEdit.Tag;
    GroupTextBox.Tag = GroupEdit.Tag;
    ...
}

private void GroupEdit_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    tag = GroupEdit1.Tag;
    // Loop through all child controls and set visibility according to tag
    for each (var c in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(GroupEdit1.Parent)
    {
        if(c is TextBox && c.Tag == tag) 
            c.Visible =Visibility.Visible;
        else if(c is TextBlock && c.Tag == tag) 
            c.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks il try this out